# Nonce cookie not being returned in Code flow, .AspNetCore.Identity.Application cookie returned instead

Tags: openiddict

We have upgraded both our application running openiddict and the client application in question to .net core 3.1 and .net framework 4.8 respectively. Openiddict is also updated to 3.1.0

Since this update, and the resulting changes in both projects, our .net framework asp.net mvc 5 application began hitting exception
IDX21323: RequireNonce is 'System.Boolean'. OpenIdConnectProtocolValidationContext.Nonce was null, OpenIdConnectProtocol.ValidatedIdToken.Payload.Nonce was not null. The nonce cannot be validated. If you don't need to check the nonce, set OpenIdConnectProtocolValidator.RequireNonce to 'false'. Note if a 'nonce' is found it will be evaluated.

Upon inspection of the redirect request from our connect/authorize endpoint back to the client application's signin callback (called signin-sevanidentity) we see that instead of receiving a cookie of OpenIdConnect.nonce like we see on our production instance we see .AspNetCore.Identity.Application which is not being recognized by the client

Callback in updated version:
[OpenIdConnect.nonce Header Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvGfC.png)

Callback in working production instance:
[ProductionHeaderInfo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlcUB.png)

Not certain if I've messed up config in openiddict, the client or both.

Answer (score 0):

I found the resolution for this specific issue.  The root cause was because I was using the incorrect response type in my client side's OpenIdConnect configuration.  I was using "code id_token" instead of "code"

When I went to modify the OpenIdConnectResponseType enum value I found that code was not one of them, only 2 options were.

It turns out I had mistakenly installed an unneeded package that overrode the extensions.
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocol.Extensions published by "Microsoft Corporation" not "Microsoft"

[Nuget Package name and version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IqlX.png)

After uninstalling this package I was able to add the code response type as intended.